# Set default value in MySQL but no set through JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, default

I have set in my tables default values for some columns.For example create_time I have set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. When I insert an object through JPA I don't get the default value for that column. Does exist any command to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `@Column` annotation (assuming you're using annotations), you can set `insertable` and `updateable` to `false` to exclude certain fields from update and insert statements. This should preserve the value that is set by MySQL.

`@Column(insertable = false, updateable = false)`

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear that.

Comment: Have you some experience in JPA?

Comment: Can you get a look to my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140540/how-to-insert-correctly-data-on-mysql-db-through-jpa-when-tables-are-linked-with